# 404 error when trying to create subgroup

Tags: http-status-code-404, gitlab

Here are some illustrations.
I've got a group without subgroups:
[image: Group without subgroups]

And when I push create subgroup, I see this:
[image: 404 error at gitlab.example.com/groups/new?parent_id=20]

Also posted this issue on [gitlab forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/404-when-trying-to-create-subgroup/7222)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into the same issue. Apparently, the button is displayed even though you don't have rights to create a new subgroup.

Here's a link to the issue: 
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/30139

Comment: hope it will be merged soon